# Threatend fields for a large person with a long spear

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, weapons, reach

Situation: 
A human character with a long spear who uses the feat "Lunge" becomes enlarged 
(as per spell). 
Question:
Which fields does he threaten? Are these the squares in 15', 20' and 25' distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The creature can attack anything within 25' of it, but can't attack anything within 10' of it.**

First, here are the pieces that are important:

[Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person):

> A humanoid creature whose size increases to Large has a space of 10 feet and a natural reach of 10 feet. This spell does not change the target's speed.
>
> ...
>
> All equipment worn or carried by a creature is similarly enlarged by the spell.

[Reach Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#reach-weapons):

> *Reach Weapons:* A reach weapon is a melee weapon that allows its wielder to strike at targets that aren't adjacent to him. Most reach weapons double the wielder's natural reach, meaning that a typical Small or Medium wielder of such a weapon can attack a creature 10 feet away, but not a creature in an adjacent square. A typical Large character wielding a reach weapon of the appropriate size can attack a creature 15 or 20 feet away, but not adjacent creatures or creatures up to 10 feet away.

[Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat---final):

> You can increase the reach of your melee attacks by 5 feet until the end of your turn[.]

The layering works as follows:

Enlarge person sets you natural reach (10'). Your long spear doubles your natural reach and adds a dead spot (20', not within 10'). Lunge then adds 5 to your reach (25', not within 10').

I've not found a great citation for reach/natural reach, but it appears to be used to segment bonuses for calculations like the above.

Your reach calculation appears to be:

```
((natural reach * natural reach bonuses) * (reach weapon modifier)) + (reach modifiers)
```

Comment: I’m not convinced by your order of effects; can you provide any citation for that? I would have assumed that lunge applies before the reach weapon, so that for that turn your reach is 15 ft. and the reach weapon modifies that (ending with a threatened area out to 30 ft. but not within 15 ft.).

Comment: @KRyan Reach weapons double a creature's "Natural Reach," and Lunge increases "Reach." There are three interpreations: 1. Natural Reach and Reach are the same (but then why do they go to the trouble of specifying the phrase "Natural" in the rules?). 2. Reach is a subset of Natural Reach (this is the interpretation you appear to be using); meaning that effects that increase Reach increase Natural Reach, but not vice versa. 3. Natural Reach is a subset of Reach (my interpretation); meaning that effects that increase Natural Reach increase Reach, but not vice versa.

Comment: @KRyan I saw a fair bit of forum chatter suggesting three, and it fits better with the way I'd use the terms. But of course that's all just hearsay. If you have a citation for the other way around, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Actually, Paizo does not use either term consistently, in my experience. I find it impossible to draw any conclusion based on them because Paizo isn’t consistent about it.

Comment: @KRyan Could you point to an example you feel is inconsistent?